# De-serialize JSON array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have a very odd JSON array as follows

> [["1","hello"],["2","hello2"],["3","hello3"],["",""],["",""],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null]]

I need to de-serialize in c# but there doesn't seem to be anything common to convert it to I tried string but then I get the follow error:

> Type string is not supported for deserialization of an array.

This is the code I tried:

```
string jsonString = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<string>(json);
```

How would you get at the strings in the JSON?

Comment: What are you using to deserialize? Have you tried taking a look at json.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could deserialize it to an array of string arrays:

```
string[][] jsonString = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<string[][]>(json);
```

Or maybe a list of string-tuples (Dictionary could be problematic due to the lack of unique keys):

```
List<Tuple<string, string>> jsonString = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialze<List<Tuple<string, string>>(json);
```

Comment: Ah your on to something that's a massive help, thanks :)